# Ripple effect within the circle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build the ripple effect on my own as following:

```js
function onMenuClick(e) {
      var dom = e.currentTarget;
      var x = e.pageX;
      var y = e.pageY;
      var rippleDiv = document.createElement("div");
      var domTokenList = rippleDiv.classList;
      domTokenList.add("ripple");
      rippleDiv.setAttribute("style", "top:" + (String(y) + ("px; left:" + (String(x) + "px;"))));
      dom.appendChild(rippleDiv);
      setTimeout((function () {
        dom.removeChild(rippleDiv);
        return /* () */0;
      }), 900);
      return /* () */0;
    }
```

```css
   body {
      background-color: coral;
    }

    .topbar-menu-on-mobile {
      display: flex;
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      background-color: #24344b;
      margin-left: 15px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .fa-bars {
      color: #2db9ba;
    }

    .ripple {
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 2px;
      height: 2px;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
      animation-duration: 1s;
      -webkit-animation-name: ripple;
      animation-name: ripple;
    }

    @keyframes ripple {
      0% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      100% {
        transform: scale(165);
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Ripple test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ"
    crossorigin="anonymous" />

</head>

<body>
  <a onclick="onMenuClick(event)" class="topbar-menu-on-mobile">

  </a>

</body>

</html>
```

When I click on the circle, the ripple effect exceed the circle. How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to the `a` so that you can use `overflow:hidden` because the ripple div will become positioned relatively to `a`. then adjust the JS code to correct the position of `div` considering the position of the element.

```js
function onMenuClick(e) {
  var dom = e.currentTarget;
  var elemRect = dom.getBoundingClientRect()
  var x = e.pageX - elemRect.left;
  var y = e.pageY - elemRect.top;
  var rippleDiv = document.createElement("div");
  var domTokenList = rippleDiv.classList;
  domTokenList.add("ripple");
  rippleDiv.setAttribute("style", "top:" + (String(y) + ("px; left:" + (String(x) + "px;"))));
  dom.appendChild(rippleDiv);
  setTimeout((function() {
    dom.removeChild(rippleDiv);
    return /* () */ 0;
  }), 900);
  return /* () */ 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: coral;
}

.topbar-menu-on-mobile {
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #24344b;
  margin-left: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
}


.ripple {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: ripple;
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(165);
  }
}
```

```html
<a onclick="onMenuClick(event)" class="topbar-menu-on-mobile">

</a>
```